# ChartJS Line Graph - Multiple Lines, Show one Value on Tooltip

Tags: chart.js

I'm trying to make a Graph which has to show the Account movement from each Customer.

**What I'm trying to do**

I've tree lines ;
First line :  The minimum balance, if the customer has less than the min. balance, his balance will auto load from his bank account.

Second Line : The current balance

Third Line: The maximum balance : If the customer has more than the max. balance he will become the difference from the system on his bank account.

### My Problem

[Link to the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pwUuM.png) : [chartjs tooltip problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pwUuM.png)

As you see in the tooltip are the all 3 values. The values of the straight lines are irrelevant for the customer because the Limits (max and min are setted from the customer his own) .

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To achieve this you can extend the line graph to add an option to show/hide tool-tips on a per dataset basses. The annoying thing is there are only a few changes but whole methods have to be overridden to get the changes in there so the below looks like a lot but its basically 3 changes to the following methods

- Initialize - added option to store showTooltip option in each point
- getPointsAtEvent - added check to make sure we want to disaply a tool tip when getting points
- showTooltip - added check again to make sure we want to dispaly a tool tip

to then use it the chart is set up the same but instead you make it a LineTooltip (thats what i have called the extended chart) and pass anextra option in the datasets call showToolip.

```
 datasets: [{
        label: "My First dataset",
        fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
        strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.8)",
        highlightFill: "rgba(220,220,220,0.75)",
        highlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        showTooltip: false, //NEW OPTION DON"T NEED TO INCLUDE IT IF YOU WANT TO DISPLAY BUT WON"T HURT IF YOU DO
        data: [15, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10]
    }, {
        label: "My second dataset",
        fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
        strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.8)",
        highlightFill: "rgba(220,220,220,0.75)",
        highlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        showTooltip: false, //NEW OPTION DON"T NEED TO INCLUDE IT IF YOU WANT TO DISPLAY BUT WON"T HURT IF YOU DO
        data: [100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100]
    }, {
        label: "My third dataset",
        fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",
        strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.8)",
        highlightFill: "rgba(151,187,205,0.75)",
        highlightStroke: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
        data: [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90]
    }]
```

i have added bigger comment banners in the below code to try and highlight where the changes got made. I have also added this feature to my fork of chartjs as this could be useful to more people https://github.com/leighquince/Chart.js, using this you can just use a normal line chart and add the showTooltip

Below is the example of extending the Line into a custom chart to include this feature, ive called in LineTooltip as but could be called anything you like that.

```js
Chart.types.Line.extend({

  name: "LineTooltip",
  /*
   * we have to add one item in the init so need to rewrite it again here with the one edit
   */
  initialize: function(data) {
    //have to get the helpers as we are using this outside chart where it was declared
    var helpers = Chart.helpers;
    //Declare the extension of the default point, to cater for the options passed in to the constructor
    this.PointClass = Chart.Point.extend({
      strokeWidth: this.options.pointDotStrokeWidth,
      radius: this.options.pointDotRadius,
      display: this.options.pointDot,
      hitDetectionRadius: this.options.pointHitDetectionRadius,
      ctx: this.chart.ctx,
      inRange: function(mouseX) {
        return (Math.pow(mouseX - this.x, 2) < Math.pow(this.radius + this.hitDetectionRadius, 2));
      }
    });

    this.datasets = [];

    //Set up tooltip events on the chart
    if (this.options.showTooltips) {
      helpers.bindEvents(this, this.options.tooltipEvents, function(evt) {
        var activePoints = (evt.type !== 'mouseout') ? this.getPointsAtEvent(evt) : [];
        this.eachPoints(function(point) {
          point.restore(['fillColor', 'strokeColor']);
        });
        helpers.each(activePoints, function(activePoint) {
          activePoint.fillColor = activePoint.highlightFill;
          activePoint.strokeColor = activePoint.highlightStroke;
        });
        this.showTooltip(activePoints);
      });
    }

    //Iterate through each of the datasets, and build this into a property of the chart
    helpers.each(data.datasets, function(dataset) {
      var datasetObject = {
        label: dataset.label || null,
        fillColor: dataset.fillColor,
        strokeColor: dataset.strokeColor,
        pointColor: dataset.pointColor,
        pointStrokeColor: dataset.pointStrokeColor,
        showTooltip: dataset.showTooltip,
        points: []
      };

      this.datasets.push(datasetObject);


      helpers.each(dataset.data, function(dataPoint, index) {
        //Add a new point for each piece of data, passing any required data to draw.
        datasetObject.points.push(new this.PointClass({

          /*
           * set wether to show the tooltip or not, left this as being able to be undfined
           * and default to true
           */
          showTooltip: dataset.showTooltip === undefined ? true : dataset.showTooltip,
          value: dataPoint,
          label: data.labels[index],
          datasetLabel: dataset.label,
          strokeColor: dataset.pointStrokeColor,
          fillColor: dataset.pointColor,
          highlightFill: dataset.pointHighlightFill || dataset.pointColor,
          highlightStroke: dataset.pointHighlightStroke || dataset.pointStrokeColor
        }));
      }, this);

      this.buildScale(data.labels);


      this.eachPoints(function(point, index) {
        helpers.extend(point, {
          x: this.scale.calculateX(index),
          y: this.scale.endPoint
        });
        point.save();
      }, this);

    }, this);


    this.render();
  },
  /*
   * need to edit how points at event works so it only uses points that we want to show the tool tip for
   */
  getPointsAtEvent: function(e) {
    //have to get the helpers as we are using this outside chart where it was declared
    var helpers = Chart.helpers;
    var pointsArray = [],
      eventPosition = helpers.getRelativePosition(e);
    helpers.each(this.datasets, function(dataset) {
      helpers.each(dataset.points, function(point) {
        if (point.inRange(eventPosition.x, eventPosition.y) && point.showTooltip) pointsArray.push(point);
      });
    }, this);
    return pointsArray;
  },
  /*
   * also need to change how the core showTooltip functions as otherwise, it trys to be helpful
   * and grab any points it thinks also need to be displayed
   */
  showTooltip: function(ChartElements, forceRedraw) {
    //have to get the helpers as we are using this outside chart where it was declared
    var helpers = Chart.helpers;
    var each = helpers.each;
    var indexOf = helpers.indexOf;
    var min = helpers.min;
    var max = helpers.min;
    // Only redraw the chart if we've actually changed what we're hovering on.
    if (typeof this.activeElements === 'undefined') this.activeElements = [];

    var isChanged = (function(Elements) {
      var changed = false;

      if (Elements.length !== this.activeElements.length) {
        changed = true;
        return changed;
      }

      each(Elements, function(element, index) {
        if (element !== this.activeElements[index]) {
          changed = true;
        }
      }, this);
      return changed;
    }).call(this, ChartElements);

    if (!isChanged && !forceRedraw) {
      return;
    } else {
      this.activeElements = ChartElements;
    }
    this.draw();
    if (ChartElements.length > 0) {
      // If we have multiple datasets, show a MultiTooltip for all of the data points at that index
      if (this.datasets && this.datasets.length > 1) {
        var dataArray,
          dataIndex;

        for (var i = this.datasets.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
          dataArray = this.datasets[i].points || this.datasets[i].bars || this.datasets[i].segments;
          dataIndex = indexOf(dataArray, ChartElements[0]);
          if (dataIndex !== -1) {
            break;
          }
        }
        var tooltipLabels = [],
          tooltipColors = [],
          medianPosition = (function(index) {

            // Get all the points at that particular index
            var Elements = [],
              dataCollection,
              xPositions = [],
              yPositions = [],
              xMax,
              yMax,
              xMin,
              yMin;
            helpers.each(this.datasets, function(dataset) {
              dataCollection = dataset.points || dataset.bars || dataset.segments;
              /*
               *check to make sure we want to show the point
               */
              if (dataCollection[dataIndex] && dataCollection[dataIndex].hasValue() && (dataCollection[dataIndex].showTooltip === undefined || dataCollection[dataIndex].showTooltip)) {
                Elements.push(dataCollection[dataIndex]);
              }
            });

            helpers.each(Elements, function(element) {
              xPositions.push(element.x);
              yPositions.push(element.y);


              //Include any colour information about the element
              tooltipLabels.push(helpers.template(this.options.multiTooltipTemplate, element));
              tooltipColors.push({
                fill: element._saved.fillColor || element.fillColor,
                stroke: element._saved.strokeColor || element.strokeColor
              });

            }, this);

            yMin = min(yPositions);
            yMax = max(yPositions);

            xMin = min(xPositions);
            xMax = max(xPositions);

            return {
              x: (xMin > this.chart.width / 2) ? xMin : xMax,
              y: (yMin + yMax) / 2
            };
          }).call(this, dataIndex);

        new Chart.MultiTooltip({
          x: medianPosition.x,
          y: medianPosition.y,
          xPadding: this.options.tooltipXPadding,
          yPadding: this.options.tooltipYPadding,
          xOffset: this.options.tooltipXOffset,
          fillColor: this.options.tooltipFillColor,
          textColor: this.options.tooltipFontColor,
          fontFamily: this.options.tooltipFontFamily,
          fontStyle: this.options.tooltipFontStyle,
          fontSize: this.options.tooltipFontSize,
          titleTextColor: this.options.tooltipTitleFontColor,
          titleFontFamily: this.options.tooltipTitleFontFamily,
          titleFontStyle: this.options.tooltipTitleFontStyle,
          titleFontSize: this.options.tooltipTitleFontSize,
          cornerRadius: this.options.tooltipCornerRadius,
          labels: tooltipLabels,
          legendColors: tooltipColors,
          legendColorBackground: this.options.multiTooltipKeyBackground,
          title: ChartElements[0].label,
          chart: this.chart,
          ctx: this.chart.ctx
        }).draw();

      } else {
        each(ChartElements, function(Element) {
          var tooltipPosition = Element.tooltipPosition();
          new Chart.Tooltip({
            x: Math.round(tooltipPosition.x),
            y: Math.round(tooltipPosition.y),
            xPadding: this.options.tooltipXPadding,
            yPadding: this.options.tooltipYPadding,
            fillColor: this.options.tooltipFillColor,
            textColor: this.options.tooltipFontColor,
            fontFamily: this.options.tooltipFontFamily,
            fontStyle: this.options.tooltipFontStyle,
            fontSize: this.options.tooltipFontSize,
            caretHeight: this.options.tooltipCaretSize,
            cornerRadius: this.options.tooltipCornerRadius,
            text: template(this.options.tooltipTemplate, Element),
            chart: this.chart
          }).draw();
        }, this);
      }
    }
    return this;
  },

});




var ctx = document.getElementById("chart").getContext("2d");
var data = {
  labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
  datasets: [{
    label: "My First dataset",
    fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
    strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.8)",
    highlightFill: "rgba(220,220,220,0.75)",
    highlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
    showTooltip: false, //TO USE JUST ADD THIS NEW OPTION ONLY REALLY NEEDS TO PRESENT IF SETTING TO FALSE
    data: [15, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10]
  }, {
    label: "My second dataset",
    fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
    strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.8)",
    highlightFill: "rgba(220,220,220,0.75)",
    highlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
    showTooltip: false, //TO USE JUST ADD THIS NEW OPTION ONLY REALLY NEEDS TO PRESENT IF SETTING TO FALSE
    data: [100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100]
  }, {
    label: "My third dataset",
    fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",
    strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.8)",
    highlightFill: "rgba(151,187,205,0.75)",
    highlightStroke: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
    data: [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90]
  }]
};


var myBarChart = new Chart(ctx).LineTooltip(data);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/1.0.2/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="chart" width="600px"></canvas>
```

and a fiddle if you find that easy to view http://jsfiddle.net/leighking2/1Lammwpt/

Comment: quite alright let me know if you see any issues with it, ive tested it but not all possibilities :)

Comment: Sure I will contact you if something works not right. Thank you again.

Comment: Hi @quince, I was wondering if you had an idea about how to go about emphazing a single point (like pointDot set to true but for a single point) I have been trying various things such as redrawing the canvas with my changes for instance but to no avail...

Comment: you can access the information for single points after the graph has been initialized. hang on ill quickly knock up an example

Comment: @AKFourSeven - http://fiddle.jshell.net/leighking2/k4663Luh/ - not the nicest way to do this as it so specific for the data but currently the only way i have seen to be able to edit the individual style of the poitns

Comment: I tried your example but it comes with two challenges:

1) It refreshes the graph and consequently reset certain modification made to the graph at the point when it is initialised

2) The point is explicitly expressed which does not work well with my graph that has 500+ values and where the point to emphasize is a random point clicked on...


I will have to keep on searching I guess, thanks for the tips though!!