# Chart.js remove dataset from tooltip

Tags: javascript, charts, tooltip, chart.js

I have a line chart with three datasets (target, profit & breakeven).
The target and profit can change, but I want the breakeven line to be drawn at 0 all the way across the graph, just as shown in the screenshot below.
What I want to remove is the breakeven label from the tooltip list.

I am using `multiTooltipTemplate: function(chartData){return chartData.datasetLabel+": £" + formatMoney(chartData.value, 2);}` to format the tooltips should this provide any help.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: answered a similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/a/26424982/2737978

Comment: @Quince This is perfect! Could you answer the question with your link and I'll accept it

Comment: nah it's the same question in essence, i'll mark this one as duplicate and that way it will point people in the right direction if they find this one.

Comment: @Quince Great, thanks